# Scrapy custom ImagePipeline - Quality settings

Tags: python, scrapy, python-imaging-library

our scraper currently not only downloads text but also images. The scraper in its current state is working fine, we have however big problems with the quality of the downloaded images.
After checking the standard ImagePipeline, we implemented a custom one that tells Pillow to use the highest quality, it looks like this (and is configured in settings.py):

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from cStringIO import StringIO

class CustomImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def convert_image(self, image, size=None):
        buf = StringIO()
        image.save(buf, 'JPEG', quality=100)
        return image, buf
```

We also tried several other presets taken from this file:
https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/JpegPresets.py

We did however not see any improvements. Did someone here tackle this problem before or has an idea what's wrong with the code?

Thanks :)

Comment: there is [a closed PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/250) I opened some time ago that added the option to *not* convert the downloaded image  at all. If that's what you need, look for `ORIGINAL_SAVE` in the modified filed. The ImagePipeline has changed since, but I plan to open a new PR to suggest it again.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the hint. I've actually found another recently merged PR that hasn't been documented yet. I'll add an answer for this shortly.

Comment: I know this PR :) (my PR also did something similar for files) indeed, also works for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this particular problem with a different approach, that was made possible by a recent pull request that hasn't been documented yet.

The pull request introduced a new pipeline, called FilesPipeline:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/files.py

I had to make the following changes to get this working:

- rename the `image_urls` field, that is used for the image pipeline, to `file_urls` in your `items.py`
- activate the pipeline in your `settings.py` and define a storage

  - `ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.files.FilesPipeline': 1}`
  - `FILES_STORE = '/Users/chris/Scrapy/project/images'`

Apart from those changes the pipeline works exactly like the image pipeline. Obviously this approach only works if you just need the file from the website in its original format.